# Send message to specific client connectionId Websocket API AWS in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to build a real-time chat app using AWS Lambda + Websocket API in API Gateway.

What I want to do is save the `connectionId` of each user in my DB to be able to send messages to specific clients when 2 users are in the same conversation for example.

How can I specify the `connectionId`s target from the `lambda` function in python?

This should actually be a list of `connectionId` to send to every people i am speaking with inside the app's current conversation.

The pseudo-code would look like (inside the `lambda`) :

```
def create_message(message, conversation):
    save_message_in_db(message)
    ids_that_should_receive_message = conversation["participantsID"]
    return {"body": json.dumps({"message": message}), "connectionId": ids_that_should_receive_message}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the `APIGatewayManagementAPI` and use the `post_to_connection` method that takes a specific `ConnectionId` parameter to send the message to a specific client :

[image: post_to_connection]

And [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigatewaymanagementapi.html#ApiGatewayManagementApi.Client.post_to_connection) is the link to the boto3 documentation where i have found it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a concrete example of using `post_to_connection` with a `APIGatewayManagementAPI` client:

```py
import boto3
from urllib.parse import urlparse

WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT = "wss://XXX7XXXXX8.execute-api.ap-XXX-X.amazonaws.com/dev/"
WEBSOCKET_CLIENT = boto3.client(
    service_name="apigatewaymanagementapi",
    endpoint_url=f"https://{urlparse(WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT).netloc}/dev",
)

data = json.dumps(
    {
        "my_data": "bla bla bla"
    }
)

WEBSOCKET_CLIENT.post_to_connection(
    Data=data.encode("utf-8"), ConnectionId=connection_id
)
```